# what is the difference between these two c++ code blocks?

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

Why is the first one able to increment pbf_[k] correctly while the second one does not even do it(increment)for once?

```
unsigned pbf_[5] ={0}; 
 bool m=0;
```

Code 1:

```
for(int k=0;k<5;k++)    
 {

  if((m=(bit_table_[k][i][bit_index ] &bit_mask[bit]))==true)    
     pbf_[k]++;
  }
```

Code 2:

```
for(int k=0;k<5;k++)    
 {
   if((bit_table_[k][i][bit_index ] & bit_mask[bit])==true)
        pbf_[k]++;
 }
```

Comment: Well you should check the value of M inside each iteration as well as after them, and you should see the difference...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, the result of the masking is converted to bool `m` before it is compared to true.

In the second case, I believe the bitmasks are some integer type. In that case `true` will be promoted to the same integer type (and have the value 1).

Just remove the `== true` from the comparison to make them equivalent.

Comment: In case @John doesn't realize, `&` is bitwise AND, not logical AND, so the result is an integer.  A nonzero integer evaluated in a boolean context is true, but it's not *equal to the value of `true` as an integer* which is 1.

Comment: Another way to fix this would be to use an explicit cast to `bool`. However, this is silly, as comparing to `true` is silly in the first place. In the same way that the phrase "it is true that" is almost always superfluous in English, `== true` is almost always superfluous in programming.

Answer (score 0):

the first on tests the result of the the assignment to m of the value of `bit_table_[k][i][bit_index ] & bit_mask[bit]`, while the second just tests whether

`bit_table_[k][i][bit_index ] & bit_mask[bit]` results not 0

Both the same effect, except that the first records the result in m on each iteration.

Comment: No, they don't have the same effect, and your description of the second test is, I believe, incorrect. See Bo Persson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You first check

```
if((m=(bit_table_[k][i][bit_index ] &bit_mask[bit]))==true)
```

is assining some value to variable m and that is taken by if as true.

Answer (score 0):

I found one problem in your code. You need to use && instead of &.
In comparison, && is an logical operator and it differs from &--Bitwise operator.

Example:

if((m=(bit_table_[k][i][bit_index ] && bit_mask[bit]))==true)

To learn about operator in C++ you can visit:http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/c++_operators.htm

Comment: No, he does want a bitwise operator because he needs to check that a specific bit is set in both values. However, he needs to **not** compare the result to `true`, because that's equivalent to comparing it to `1`, when it may be some other nonzero value even on a "match". @BoPersson has it right.